# In Java, is there a way to format the output of a double/int or non-string variable?

Tags: java, formatting

I realize this sounds simple, and probably is...
Say this the code within main(), which is inside of a loop:

```
System.out.println(num[i]+"\t     "+qty[i]+"\t     "+money.format(price[i])+"\t"+money.format(value[i])+"\t"+reorder[i]);
```

with the total captured here:

http://maradastudios.ucoz.com/school/Capture.png

as you may have noticed, it works fine.  However, during the output the line of #114 (2nd to last line) has a total value of $90.00.  This is correct, but it causes odd spacing for the Reorder Point variable.  To state it simply, can I format this variable to take up the same amount of space as it's larger-digited counterparts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
String.format("%10.2f", yourFloat)
// or
System.out.format("%10.2f", yourFloat)
```

Will print a 10-character wide (including decimal) string, with two numeric characters after the decimal.

([Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29))

So

```
String.format("$%6.2f", value[i])
```

will align both the `$` and `.` characters (unless `value[i] > 999.99`).

---

Instead of:

```
System.out.println(
    num[i]                +"\t     "+
    qty[i]                +"\t     "+
    money.format(price[i])+"\t"+
    money.format(value[i])+"\t"+
    reorder[i]);
```

(which is exactly what you had, just formatted for clarity and to remove the scroll bar)

I'd  probably write:

```
System.out.format("%5d\t %5d\t $%5.2f\t $%6.2f\t %5d %n", 
    num[i], qty[i], price[i], value[i], reorder[i]);
```

This assumes that the `price` and `value` arrays are floats or doubles.  Since `money` isn't a standard class, it's hard to tell exactly what it does other than add a `$` sign.

---

The string format syntax is defined in the docs, but for floats it's **roughly**:

```
%X.Yf
```

Where `X` is the total field width and `Y` is the number of decimal points

For example

```
"123.40"  Has a total width of 6:  
          3 + 1 [decimal point] + 2 = 6)
"  2.34"  Also has a total width of 6:
          2 [spaces] + 1 + 1 [decimal point] + 2 = 6
```

Comment: I don't mean to sound uneducated in Java, but I'm just starting it, but could you please explain the significance/purpose of the "%10.2f"?  Also, since I'm displaying them in a System.out.println() form, would I simply have to use it like this...
    System.out.println(String.format("%10.2f", value[i]));
...or like this?
    System.out.format("%10.2f", value[i]+"\t"+othervariableshere);

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I just tried that method, and I couldn't get more than one variable in one line without using multiple statements.  I'm looking to do something like this:
    System.out.format("$%3.2f", price[i]+"\t"+num[i]);
but I could only get it to work like this:
    System.out.format("$%3.2f", price[i]);
    System.out.println("\t"+num[i]);

Any way to do that in a single line/statement?

Comment: Yep, just added something like that in.  `System.out.format` will accept as many parameters as you give it, provided you pass  them correctly.

Comment: Without looking at the logic behind the code, if you're trying to do this `System.out.format("$%3.2f", price[i]+"\t"+num[i]);` then you should do it like this: `System.out.format("$%3.2f\t"+num[i], price[i]);`

Comment: So basically, what I do is...
    System.out.format("%1.1f\t%1.1f\t%1.1f\t" var1, var2, var3);
if I would want to format those 3 variables to those parameters?

Additionally, since you referred to 'money' as a class, it was used in my program after "NumberFormat money=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();", so it just formatted the double to currency.

Comment: Exactly.  But the `%1.1f` syntax won't work as you expect, if you meant any more from that than an example.

Answer (score -1):

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    System.out.println(formatter.format("%20s %20s %20s %20s %20s", "Title*", "Title*", "Title*", "Title*", "Title*"));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        formatter = new Formatter();

        System.out.println(formatter.format("%20s %20s %20s %20s %20s", num[i],qty[i],money.format(price[i]),money.format(value[i]),reorder[i]));
    }
```

Comment: I'd consider it, but it seems rather lengthy and impractical, especially as how I'm trying to do this on one println() statement if possible.